# How many questions can I watch via WebSockets at the same time?

Tags: support, rate-limiting, web-sockets

Stack Exchange provides a way to watch a question (i.e. receive real-time information about up- and downvotes, new answers, new comments, edits, closures and deletions) via WebSockets. You just have to connect to `qa.sockets.stackexchange.com` and send the following message:

```
SITE_ID-question-QUESTION_ID
```

where `SITE_ID` is ID of the site the question belongs to (for example `1` for Stack Overflow), and `QUESTION_ID` is ID of the question.

I don't know if it's a bug or a feature, but you can watch multiple questions using a single WebSocket connection.

I would like to watch a large amount of questions, for example 10,000. Is this allowed?

Comment: I know there are restrictions in place specifically to deal with scrapers not throttling their requests at appropriate levels, so I'd expect that you'd end up with your IP blocked doing that kind of thing.

Comment: @Servy Yes, but I think that WebSockets don't require as much resources as HTTP requests, so the limit could be higher.

Comment: FWIW, Smokey had been holding on the question websockets for ten minutes after every report to monitor deletions. It's nowhere near ten thousand, but it's definitely more than one or two concurrently.

Comment: @Undo we could count that, just monitor how many reports we get at about 7 in the morning for ten minutes.

Answer (score 5):

Because of lack of answer from any SE employee, I decided to test it by myself. Actually, it is possible to watch 10k questions with a single connection. However, you can't send too many messages at once — after sending about 450 messages without any delay, I was disconnected. Adding 1ms delay between messages is enough.

Of course the fact that the system allows to do this doesn't necessarily  mean that it's OK to do this. I still await an official answer.

Answer (score 4):

At peak load, the SE servers see [500k simultaneous websocket connections](https://nickcraver.com/blog/2016/02/17/stack-overflow-the-architecture-2016-edition/). The average is more like 370k simultaneous.

A good rule of thumb: don't open so many sockets that you're a significant part of that number. Given the millions of users, significant is subjective, but I'd set it at no more than 1% of average load.

That gives you 3700 simultaneous we sockets to play with, which is probably more than enough for most purposes. If you're watching 10k questions, you may need to narrow down why you need to, and optimise the number you actually *need* to watch. Also - explicitly close the connections as soon as you can when you're done with the socket.

If you're watching questions on the same socket, that's more than enough - you can have 3333 open sockets, each watching 3 questions, to distribute the load.

<sub>I'm not an SE developer; this is my best estimate. Use at your own risk.</sub>

Comment: I don't understand, why would I use more than one socket?

Comment: @Gothdo to spread the load across connections.